# What to call someone who is unable/bad in holding a converstation

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

Okay, So I am in often in a conversation with this person. But I have now realized that all our talks have been futile because he keeps on repeating the same topics. Topics I have talked about before.

I just want to tell him you are '*x word*' and don't want to continue having conversations with him.

Comment: This is a poor question for our site because there can be no one right answer to this. More importantly, there is no way that having us provide you with a long and random list of rude words for you to call someone is going to solve the problem that you're having with that person. You should consider visiting our site dealing with [interpersonal.se] instead. No magic word can fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person is a **poor [conversationalist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conversationalist)**:

> one who converses a great deal or who excels in conversation a witty conversationalist

Answer (score 1):

I would call them a bore, but probably not to their face because I am too polite.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/bore#bore_Noun_200

> bore: *noun*, a person whose talk or behavior is dull and uninteresting.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I prefer the term poindexter, because it is a playful insult.

Comment: @JesseIvy, but I don't think poindexter is really appropriate to this situation. I think a poindexter is someone who is overly academic or pedantic, but doesn't necessarily repeat themselves a lot. A poindexter could actually say a lot of interesting stuff but at inappropriate times or to the wrong audience.